# jenkinsfile not able to run Terraform

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I want to manually run my jenkinsfile and should be able to pull `main.tf` from the github repo 
 https://github.com/choppyfish46/terraform.git

Here is what i did and I am not able to figure out what is wrong

1)create a new pipeline project in jenkins
2)on pipeline tab copy the jenkinsfile
3)"Build now" errors out

console output

```
Started by user my_user
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_terraform
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking only exact matches of $SECRET_KEY or $ACCESS_KEY
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TerraformInit)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_terraform/jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform init -input=false
[0m[1mTerraform initialized in an empty directory![0m

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TerraformFormat)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_terraform/jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform fmt -list=true -write=false -diff=true -check=true
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TerraformPlan)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_terraform/jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform workspace new null
[0m[32m[1mCreated and switched to workspace "null"![0m[32m

You're now on a new, empty workspace. Workspaces isolate their state,
so if you run "terraform plan" Terraform will not see any existing state
for this configuration.[0m
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform plan -var access_key=**** -var secret_key=**** -out terraform.tfplan
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mNo configuration files found!

Plan requires configuration to be present. Planning without a configuration
would mark everything for destruction, which is normally not what is desired.
If you would like to destroy everything, please run plan with the "-destroy"
flag or create a single empty configuration file. Otherwise, please create
a Terraform configuration file in the path being executed and try again.[0m

[0m[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TerraformApply)
Stage "TerraformApply" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: `jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline` appears to be an empty directory, so fixing the directory is probably the first thing to do. Defining a parameter for `WROKSPACE` is also a nice to have here.

Comment: ok fixed the env variable , if I run the jenkinsfile with "build now" how would my main.tf file be copied to the workspace directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I am not sure where this directory comes from

`jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline/`

Did you try again with removing below part?

```
 dir('jenkins-terraform-pipeline/ec2_pipeline/'){
```

Comment: deleting the above line(s) and updating the workspace environment var and using "build with scm" option I am able to automate the pipeline .. thanks Matt and BMW